# What is the NetBeans keyboard shortcut for code generation for child class constructors?

Tags: ide, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, netbeans6.8

I was coding in NetBeans (PHP) today, and my hand slipped while I was typing a constructor. It must have hit a keyboard shortcut, because a constructor that was designed for a child class appeared on my screen (i.e. it called the parent constructor, so it's not the `Insert Code -> Constructor`, I don't think). Does anyone know what the shortcut is?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it Alt-Insert?

Answer (score 0):

On a PC:
`Alt` + `Insert`

On a MAC:
`Control` + `I`